# Confused between Justify-content:, align-items: & text-align

Tags: css, flexbox

Heh, I am a novice in web development. I am confused where to use CSS properties: Justify-content:, align-items: & text-align. I understand the flexbox concept but it is so confusing sometimes. Is there any quick way or cheatsheet to find out which CSS property to use?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 2):

**Justify-content:**

On short `justify-content` align the content of a container (as the name suggest). This can be for example one or more children of a component. You should this when you want to align other containers in general (ex. buttons, divs, inputs, etc).

**Warning!** As @Aman Sharma mentioned `justify-content`

> defines how the browser distributes space between and around content items along the **main-axis** of a flex container

This means that if you are using `flex-direction: column`, the main axis will be y-axis (so justify-content: center will actually center elements vertically while `align-item: center` will do the job for horizontal align).

(In contradiction if you use `flex-direction: row`, or you don't specify the direction, `justify-content:center` will center the content horizonal).

**Align-items**

As you can probably guess by this point the vertical align is somehow similar with `justify-content` but that is only partial true. While `align-items: center` does the job of centering the children of a container on the cross axis, there are some differences. One of the most obvious is that they don't share all properties (`justify-content` has `space-between`, `space-arround`, etc. while `align-items` has `baseline`, `self-start` and so on).

To understand this better (and flexbox in general) I am afraid there are no shortcuts. But I would recommend you to try to find a tutorial that you feel it suits you (video or text - doesn't really matter), and try to play a little with them.

**Text-align**

One of the main differences between `text-align` + `vertical-align` and `justify-content` + `align-items` is that the first pair is working only on **block elements** while the second is working only on **flex containers**.

Also, as you can read in the definitions posted by Aman : `text-align` always sets the horizontal alignment (you can't switch block elements content direction).

**Conclusion**

If you play a little with this 3 options (using containers) you should be able to spot a lot of differences between flex and block display as well as differences between `justify-content`, `align-items` and `text-align`.

An obvious one would be that, when using containers as children (so not text), a `display: block` container would require the children to have `inline` role in flow layout (so one of `display: inline`, `display: inline-block`, `display: inline-flex`, etc.) while for a flex container (with `justify-content: center`) this is not mandatory.

I only listed a few of the most significant differences for the sake of example and in order to try to give you a hint why there is no short answer, quick way or cheatsheet. But there are other important differences so I can only advise you again to search for some tutorials and play with them in code.

Answer (score 0):

**justify-content** - property defines how the browser distributes space between and around content items along the main-axis of a flex container, and the inline axis of a grid container.

**align-items** - property sets the align-self value on all direct children as a group. In Flexbox, it controls the alignment of items on the Cross Axis.

**text-align** - property sets the horizontal alignment of the content inside a block element or table-cell box. This means it works like vertical-align but in the horizontal direction.